# Check Point - Connect under Linux - snx + OTP

Tags: linux, checkpoint

We have a Check Point Mobile appliance at work and the Linux client is horrible, I can connect but for that I need:

- Old unsupported Oracle Java installed and enabled in the browser
- Plenty of 32-bit libs
- Run the browser as root

They also have upgraded the appliance now so I can upgrade Java, and if I give it some time I think I can remove the root requirements from the browser.

I'm trying to use the provided tools, but OpenVPN/SSH tunnels looks more interesting every day. The good thing is that we have the VPN-guy on our side so minor changes in the appliance is a valid option.

I'm trying to connect without Java if possible, and preferably from the command line/a script. I have tried to use the snx binary downloaded from the appliance but I get stuck on the OTP part, when I connect to the firewall through the browser a SMS message is sent to my phone and I enter a 6 digit number, I have found no way to do this outside the browser.

Has anyone any experience with snx/Linux and OTP auth?

Answer (score 2):

For OTP without a browser/Java, from the command line, you might use the `snxconnect` client from the snxvpn project. https://github.com/agnis-mateuss/snxvpn

The `snxconnect` is a script in python which tried to reverse engineer the missing bits that were dropped from the `snx`binary *and* the web interface to use the Checkpoint VPN from Linux.

The `snxconnect` script is a layer on top of  `snx`, and it says it supports OTP. Never tried it, as we do not use OTP.

The `snxvpn` straight installed from `pip` does not work. For details how to install `snxconnect` see this question: [getting Checkpoint VPN SSL Network Extender working in the command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450229/getting-checkpoint-vpn-ssl-network-extender-working-in-command-line/453727) (hint: it is not the accepted answer)

PS. The browser does not has to be run as root, only `snx` (it happens by default, as it is a *setuid* binary). See [VPN SSL Network Extender in Firefox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450131/vpn-ssl-network-extender-in-firefox) ; but using old versions of both Firefox and Java.

As for *pure* `snx` without `snxvpn`/`snxconnect`, I am able to install and run it, however, as said, not using OTP.

Comment: I tried the `-MC` (MULTI_CHALLENGE) param for OTP and no luck, couldn't get it to work. Also, not sure if I need to to specify something with `-L` (LOGIN_TYPE) ?