# VPN SSL Network Extender in Firefox

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, checkpoint

I need to connect from a Debian Stretch amd64 VM to a CheckPoint corporate VPN.

I am using it from the customer point of view, and do not know much technical details about the server side. I am using it with the CheckPoint Mobile client in Windows, and I know it accepts Web VPN connections with Firefox+Java aka SSL Network Extender.

I have tried opening it up in Firefox in Linux, but did not work. I also investigated text mode alternatives, namely the `snx` command line client, however CheckPoint literature clearly states direct logins from `snx` in the command line, are no longer supported.

I made several tests, inclusive installing the `snx` linux client, `snxconnect` and the `openconnect/vpnc` VPN client without much success. I also somewhat suspect the CheckPoint side besides the already convoluted process, is double-checking for the user agent, at least in my case.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 2022, and whist my previous answer is still valid por pre-R80 checkpoint releases, the world has moved on. Firefox no longer runs Java applets, so CheckPoint moved the middleware Java applet to the client/Linux side as a Java daemon - CShell daemon (around 2 years ago).

The SNX SSL Network Extender daemon, despite the executable binary unfortunately still being 32 bits, now besides using SSLv3 tunneling for old firewalls, supports and works only with TLS 1.2 for the new firewalls. It also has light changes to make it incompatible with the snxconnect python reverse engineering effort.

On the other hand, there is no longer a requirement for the Mobile Access Portal Agent (CShell) neither of using Java 8 nor an Oracle Java implementation nor a specific Firefox version. It has successfully tested with several CheckPoint versions using openJDK
JRE 11.

While helping a development team of ours adapting to the new scenario, I initially wrote instructions for Debian, then in a 2nd version patches for cshell_install.sh because of it being badly behaved. Eventually arrived to the conclusion you might not want your machine being encumbered by having to have multiarch with 32-bits active, or Java, or having to patch any new cshell_install.sh variation.

As such, wrote instructions for having SNX plus the "new" CShell Java daemon in a chroot. However the document was too big, and wrote a script for Debian.

Eventually, the script evolved, to fake requirements instead of patching CheckPoint's scripts, and to support most of the main distributions, far more than using the SNX + cshell_install.sh in their "naked" official form (which for instance latest versions of Fedora no longer support).

You can fetch it here:

https://github.com/ruyrybeyro/chrootvpn

For getting and installing the script to automagically create a chroot and make your VPN work, you have to use a user that is configure for sudo and do:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ruyrybeyro/chrootvpn/main/vpn.sh -O
chmod a+rx vpn.sh
./vph.sh -i --vpn=VPN_FQDN_DNS_NAME
```

Any derivate distributions of Debian/Ubuntu, SUSE or RedHat/CentOS/Fedora are supported.
Any variation of Arch too, as long it is configured with Network Manager.
Slackware, Void and Gentoo Linux too.

---

---

Nonetheless, if not using the script above, the instructions for Debian, for a plain, official, non chrooted setup are:

Open the Mobile Portal VPN in the browser, https://VPN_FW_HOSTNAME, and authenticate with user and password(+double factor PIN if any); when the browser asks if you want to save a password, select “Never save”

Select settings. Change defaults to:

When signing-in launch SSL Network Extender: automatically
Connect SSL Network Extender using: Network mode

Select OK.

Close the browser.

Download Linux Clients setup scripts from the firewall:

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate https://VPN_FW_HOSTNAME/SNX/INSTALL/snx_install.sh
$ wget --no-check-certificate https://VPN_FW_HOSTNAME/SNX/INSTALL/cshell_install.sh
```

Run:

chmod a+rx snx_install.sh cshell_install.sh

Installing SNX:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install libstdc++5:i386 libx11-6:i386 libpam0g:i386
$ sudo ./snx_install.sh
```

Install firefox, before installing the Java agent:

```
$ sudo apt install firefox-esr
```

Run Firefox and close it.

Having installed firefox-esr, for compatibility with the CheckPoint cshell_install.sh script:

```
$ ln -s ~/.mozilla/firefox-esr ~/.mozilla/firefox
```

Be sure to open it for the user profile to be created. It is essential to call it using the non-privileged user that it will be daily used. Failure in having already run/having a Firefox/Chrome profile under /home, means cshell_install.sh will not meet minimum requirements and will abort setup.

Installing Mobile access Portal Agent

```
$ sudo apt install xauth x11-xserver-utils certutil libnss3-tools openjdk-11-jdk
```

For the next step, firefox must not be running:

```
$ sudo ./cshell_install.sh
```

If the installation went well:

```
# ps ax | grep cshell
  14224 pts/0 Sl 0:01 java -jar /usr/bin/cshell/CSell.jar /tmp/cshell.fifo
  14300 pts/0 S+ 0:00 grep cshell
```

The CShell daemon must be running now. In case it is not:

```
$ /usr/bin/cshell/launcher
```

To verify that the certificate has been installed, you can also do:

```
$ wget -q -O- --no-check-certificate https://localhost:14186/id
```

Finally enter firefox again, and visit

https://localhost:14186/id

to accept the https://localhost:14186 CheckPoint self-signed certificate.

Authenticate again with your login, and your password(+double factor PIN if any) in the firewall mobile portal address.

The connection to the VPN should now be automatic. If not, click on Connect.

Be aware that following the manual steps without the chroot script, cshell_install.sh install requirements are finicky and if not met, it aborts.

Relevant CheckPoint Linux support pages:

SSL Network Extender
https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk65210#Linux%20Supported%20Platforms

How to install SSL Network Extender (SNX) client on Linux machines
https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk114267

Mobile Access Portal Agent Prerequisites for Linux
https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk119772

Mobile Access Portal and Java Compatibility
https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk113410

Mobile Access Portal Agent for Mozilla Firefox asks to re-install even after it was properly installed
https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk122576&partition=Advanced&product=Mobile

Comment: It worked! But I had to do some extra step. The "cshell_install.sh" was looking for the folder "~/.mozilla/firefox" to install/remove the certificates, but with Firefox ESR, there's only the folder "~/.mozilla/firefox-esr". I just closed Firefox, rename the folder to "~/.mozilla/firefox" temporarily, and then it was able to install the certificates. After that, I changed the folder back to it's original name. Everything is working like a charm! Thank you a lot! I've tried so many solutions, and only this one worked for me. Cheers mate. 

Comment: @LuísAssunção cshell_install/snx got loads of lib files and applicational dependencies, and some cannot even be satisfied in some recent distributions. Eventually I also gave up on patching cshell install, because CheckPoint has several variations over time. Hence why I created the script for a chroot setup, where I can fake them at will. The script also installs a global Firefox policy instead of mucking up with the user certificate store copy. Cheers mate

Comment: @LuísAssunção Thanks, edited the answer with your remarks. Also, from my comments, it can be inferred snx and cshell_install.sh should not be loaded randomly from the Internet and downloaded from appliance instead.

Answer (score 7):

*These 2018 instructions are for older CheckPoint VPN pre R80 (R80.10?) releases.* See the new accepted answer for newer VPN/firewalls.

Ultimately, I decided to settle on authenticating with Firefox+Java (*and then later on, changed my mind, see the related link at the bottom*). The VM itself does not run Java nor a graphical interface, and I am running Firefox on a remote X server on my notebook when I need  to connect to our corporate network.

The procedure is roughly:

1. Installing `firefox`
2. Downloading the `snx` Linux client installation *after* logging in the Web VPN client interface
3. Installing JDK
4. After everything installed, accessing the VPN URL in `firefox` each time you need to use the VPN.
5. Closing the VPN via `firefox`

As for the actual steps guide:

1. After some tests, it is evident the latest `firefox` version does not cut it running the Java applet.

> Firefox 52 and above
>
> Beginning with Firefox 52 (released March 2017), plug-in support is
> limited to Adobe Flash, and drops support for NPAPI, impacting plugins
> for Java, Silverlight, and other similar NPAPI based plugins.

So after testing a couple of `firefox` older versions, I settled for `firefox 48` that will be just used to login in the VPN. Downloaded it from the [firefox archives](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/48.0/linux-x86_64/en-GB/).

So in your target directory, do:

```
tar -jxvf  firefox-48.0.tar.bz2
```

Then do:

```
cd firefox
```

To prevent it from updating to a more recent version the first time you run on this directory:

```
sudo touch updates
sudo chattr +i updates
```

Note: the first time you run it, you also disable updates either with:

- menu icon->Preferences->Advanced->Updates

or:

- opening the URL about:preferences#advanced

and in "Firefox Updates" select the radio button: "Never check for updates"

2. If in the VPN, to get the installation file, do:

   wget --no-check-certificate https://VPN_FW_HOSTNAME/SNX/INSTALL/snx_install.sh

Alternatively, download the application from the Web VPN interface, in  "Settings->Edit Native application settings SSL Network Extender: Download Installation for Linux"

[image: snxurl]

That will get you a `snx_install.sh` file.

You also need to select: "When signing-in launch SSL Network Extender:" change it to "automatically".

Run then:

```
chmod a+rx snx_install.sh
sudo ./snx_install.sh`
```

You will have know a `/usr/bin/snx` 32-bit client binary executable. Check what dynamic libraries are missing with:

```
sudo ldd /usr/bin/snx
```

For Debian, I you might need:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

I had to install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386 libx11-6:i386 libpam0g:i386
```

Check again if any dynamic libraries are missing (if any) with:

```
sudo ldd /usr/bin/snx
```

You can only proceed to the following point when all the dependencies are satisfied, as the Java applet uses `snx` behind the scenes.

3. After several unsuccessful iterations and web crawling, found it is needed to install  Java 6 from Sun. So got `jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin` [from the Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html).

To install it do as root:

```
mkdir /usr/java
mv jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin /usr/java
cd /usr/java
chmod a+rx jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
./jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
```

We won´t configure the whole system to use this Java version as it is too old. Just to use Java with Firefox later on:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
sudo ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so libnpjp2.so
```

Now the Java installation is finished.

4. Finally, to run firefox *as a regular user* do:

   ./firefox

If the Java Applet/SSL Network Extender does not launch itself after authentication, do "Native Applications->Connect". It will open a popup/Java Window. Wait for "Status: connected".

[image: extender]

You can then close the main FireFox window.

After the VPN being established, you can check with `ip address` or `ifconfig` you have now a `tunsnx` interface:

```
$ ip addr show dev tunsnx
14: tunsnx: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.x.x.x peer 10.x.x.x/32 scope global tunsnx
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::acfe:8fce:99a4:44b7/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip route` will show you also new routes going through the `tunsnx` interface.

For extra convenience, you can define as your home page, the URL of the WebVPN.

5. To close the VPN, you either press the "Disconnect" button in the Java popup, or close/kill Firefox.

See related:  [getting Checkpoint VPN SSL Network Extender working in the command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450229)

Comment: Thanks for this! This was a really well written guide on how to do all of this... still having issues with Java but this got me close.

Comment: @saleetzo see the related link, you might be able to get away doing it without Java if you are willing to do it from the command line.

Comment: You are a good man and you guide worked great! Finally, I don't have to carry around a windows VM just for VPN. Great work and well done!

Comment: @saleetzo Pretty much was the same incentive, this allowed me to convince people at work I could ditch the corporate Windows requirement for good.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Just note, better for java download is this link. http://85-207-0-21.static.bluetone.cz/java/1.6.0_45/

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro And just question, now i see route table with new routes, so could I set this new routes without this vpn? For just one IP for example? With `route` command?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro And now I tried JDK1.8, ok with that. And what about some bash script with entering passcode, then open firefox with parameters, and open only SNX/extender with this paramaters?

Comment: @genderbee Yeah, Java links change over time...but that one seems a private link. Will check it out better. Routes that come with the VPN, if the infra-structure is well setup in terms of security, only usually work over a VPN. For an expect script, see my post about setting up snx for using it over the command line. I gave up using the method on this post once I found it I could use it over the command line, no more Java and Firefox dependencies. See the link at the end of this answer.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro THANKS! It works without java and FF! :) And what about token generator on linux? I tried `stoken`, but it generate more digits and seems it doesn't works. On android, application name is `RSA SecurID`. Thanks.

Comment: @genderbee As far as I am aware those are proprietary algorithms, they were  reversed eng in the 90s, but were probably changed. Probably no linux app, ask on another thread

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Ok, thanks. And last question. We have ugly RDP to windows 7, and then, from this ugly jum point, we can connect via putty to linux server. Quite stupid. Is any way to connect to linux server directly? Through this windows 7 jump point as tunnel? Is some ssh server needed on windows 7 jp, or is it possible through putty? Thanks.

Comment: @genderbee MobaXterm free can make two tunnels, I think putty can do it too. Ask for a Linux jumpbox. Linux shop here...

Answer (score 4):

To use the latest version of firefox, once you have installed `snx_install.sh` and `cshell_install.sh` open https://localhost:14186/id in a separate Firefox tab and add a Security Exception for site "https://localhost:14186/". Once the exception is added, you will see a unique identifier in HEX format. You can now close this tab and try to connect again.

Comment: I'm just accepting the unsigned certificate in the browser, and then the connection to the vpn works. I tested it on the latest version of Chrome and Firefox

Comment: At the time we were stuck with an older CheckPoint release. We have had R80 now for quite some time, wrote a wrapper for setting up this. I install a policy for the localhost certificate. will write a more detailed answer later on https://github.com/ruyrybeyro/chrootvpn

Answer (score 2):

@ Kubuntu 18.04 32-bit, Firefox 75.0 (32-bit), openjdk-8

One should add to firefox an exception for page https://localhost:14186/id,
that was problem in my case, applet started but didn't want to proceed because it hasn't right to get this https://localhost:14186/id

Also I should note, that I've successfully started vpn at Firefox 75.0 (32-bit) 
and openjdk-8, without downgrading to Firefox 48 and jdk-6u45, although I tried this as well, and cshell_install.sh didn't want to install at jdk-6u45

But anyway great thanks to the author of answer - Rui F Ribeiro. Helped me very much

Comment: Things changed, at the time of my question/answer, it was a Java apllet.