# How to connect to CheckPoint VPN on Ubuntu 18.04LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, checkpoint

I need to connect to Checkpoint VPN (using login & pass authentication method).
For Windows I'm able to connect, using their client, CheckPoint Endpoint Connect.
But i was not able to find the above client for linux too (not available).
Is there another way to connect to this VPN, rather than having to switch on Windows?

Comment: See this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450131/vpn-ssl-network-extender-in-firefox